# How to parse time having milliseconds and offset?

Tags: java, java-time

I want to parse the following time string to `java.time`:

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("00:00:00.000+02:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_TIME);
```

Result:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '00:00:00.000+02:00' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {OffsetSeconds=7200},ISO resolved to 00:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1918)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1853)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
```

So how could I then parse this time, if not this way?

Comment: You're parsing a **date** time, where's the date?

Comment: Hint: Use `OffsetTime`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: Doh... Could you add this as an answer. Even though it should be obvious, obviously for me it was not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) represents

> an immutable representation of a date-time with an offset. **This class stores all date and time fields**, to a precision of nanoseconds, as well as the offset from UTC/Greenwich.

But you're trying to parse a date string without a date part

```
"00:00:00.000+02:00"
```

The parsing cannot extract a date from this and therefore fails.

You seem to want to use an [`OffsetTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html)

> **This class stores all time fields**, to a precision of nanoseconds, as
>   well as a zone offset.

You can then convert that to an `OffsetDateTime`, if you have a `LocalDate`, with `OffsetTime#atDate`.